# I'm having difficulty changing upload size via Drupal / .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal

I put these lines:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
```

into the box that says:

> Custom Settings - Copy/paste below your custom settings (redirections, rewrite rules etc..). These will be added before the Drupal rules.

However, they won't register and I still am stuck at the default 2 MB upload size. How can I fix this? I'm using Drupal in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to increase PHP memory size limitation or upload size, you can use one of the following:

**Modifying the php.ini, provided you have the access.**

1. Locate the php.ini file you are currently using, you can use the phpinfo() function to find it.
2. Change the memory_limit or upload size parameter in the php.ini file. Something like:

   memory_limit = 32M ;
   upload_max_filesize = 10M
   post_max_size = 10M
3. Restart Apache. Many hosts take care of this, and all you have to do is save the file.

**.htaccess**

Look for the .htaccess file in the Drupal root directory, then, go to section that reads:

# Override PHP settings. More in sites/default/settings.php

# but the following cannot be changed at runtime.

right after these lines, add the following line:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
php_value post_max_size 32M
```

**settings.php**

Edit sites/default/settings.php. This will only affect the site using this file.

Search for the PHP settings section, add the following line at the end of that section:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','32M');
ini_set('post_max_size','32M');
```

Apache most likely will have to be restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Put those setting in index.php - preferably right after the opening

Of course, you'll need to use ini_set() function

```
<?php

ini_set('upload_max_filesize','10M');
ini_set('post_max_size','10M');
```

Comment: So just add that to the php page instead of the Admin -> Config -> Htaccess? I'll give it a try

Comment: Your other option is to put them in the .htacess file

Comment: I'm just wondering where I can find the .htaccess file via Drupal. I thought the Admin -> Config -> Htaccess allows me to add to the .htaccess file.

Comment: You probably have such file in the website root directory. But if you're not using Apache, you won't see such file

Comment: I'm not using Apache. I just login as admin to change the html and I installed the video module and then tried to upload a file that was bigger than 2MB. That's what brought me here. Is there a way to change through Drupal? I'm still new to Drupal.

Comment: If you don't use apache, do what I suggested in my answer.

Comment: Where would I put the php though? Directly onto the html page? I can't find the index.php file.